# How to make this base-10 metric time concept work

Tags: technology, time, computers, engineering

I am trying to make a fake metric-time app to prank some friends when we take a trip to Canada soon and would like to know how I could make this work conceptually.

I already know that the time is already considered "metric", but for this prank to work, the prank-ee must believe that it is not.

So, if we assume that "regular time"  means the time scale that everyone in the world uses, (24 hours in a day, 60 seconds in a minute, 60 minutes in an hour etc.), then how would I go about somehow linking "regular time" with "metric time" (100 hours in a day, 100 seconds in a minute, 100 minutes in an hour) so as to create a believable metric time clock.

(by believable, I mean not making seconds go by *excessively* fast in order to compensate for the 913,600 extra seconds in the day)

**To put it simply**
I want to somehow make a believable time scale based on powers of 10 that could feasibly replace our current timekeeping system, while still being tied to our current timescale (so 80:00 AM "metric time" would fall at the same time everyday).

Bonus points if you can explain a realistic way to do this where each increment (i.e. seconds in a minute, minutes in an hour etc.) is the same.

Extra bonus points if someone can propose a solution where I won't have to implement a massive time-jump at midnight in order to make the times correlate.

I understand that this may not be the best place to ask this question, but since I'm not asking how to implement this in code, but rather how the *concept* would work. Therefore I figured this would be the best place to ask.

Comment: Have you trie making the day 1,000,000 seconds? Then you can hack it up from there.

Comment: I want this to be pseudo believable, if i make the number of seconds per day in "metric" time any greater than "regular" time, then I will need to implement a time jump at midnight in order to make the same metric time fall on the same part of the (real) day so as to make it somewhat convincing.

Comment: What xandar meant is that you should calculate, how many milliseconds of real time equal a millionth of the total in a day. Then you can go from there and let your clock tick up by one, everytime this amount of milliseconds passed

Comment: Have there be 10 hours in a day?

Comment: Why make up something new? Just take a look at Swatch's attempt at global internet time, ".beats". Large bonus: You can get actual, legitimate time pieces like wrist watches that display .beats time.

Comment: I'm currently reviewing the standing Close-Vote for this question. You give me a hard time with it. On one side, this can be a good question being on-topic if it were for example about a new state introducing their own time (because the normal 24-system is used by THEM), but as it stands it is simply a prank. Of course I don't want to force you to come up with something just to justify my opinion. Primarily opinion-based is also slightly valid, though I believe you gave a good criterium when an answer is valid. Can someone show me a meta-post about my first point, otherwise I make one?

Comment: @J_F_B_M: I feel like the question as it stands is probably definitely off-topic, but at the same time it's highly related to what a number of people already do while building worlds. Like, "what's a good way to devise a metric time-keeping system with x, y, z properties that the new Emperor of the world could use without unduly influencing the standard perception of time?".

Comment: People at [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) would _love_ this question. That site has a certain love for pranks and out-of-the-box thinking. Also, they love questions with the words "bonus points"!

Comment: @ThalesPereira should I post it there?

Comment: @ACE It would more well accepted that on Worldbuilding SE, that's for sure. I would give it a try!

Comment: @ThalesPereira well I already have an answer here...

Comment: The French revolutionaries that stuck us with the metric system also tried to impose decimal timekeeping: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_time#France

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In imperial units, a mile is divided into yards, feet, and inches (like days are divided into hours, minutes and seconds).  However, in the metric system the subunits are based on powers of ten and named with prefixes: the *kilo*meter is divided into meters, *centi*meters, *milli*meters, etc.

For a metric time system, I would apply the same concept to the base unit of one day.  Instead of hours and minutes, you would have subunits like centidays and millidays.

For example, `10:18:42 pm` would be equal to:

$$
\frac{1}{2}~\text{day} + \frac{10~\text{hours}}{24~\text{hours}/\text{day}} + \frac{18~\text{minutes}}{24\times 60~\text{minutes}/\text{day}} + \frac{42~\text{seconds}}{24\times 60\times 60~\text{seconds}/\text{day}} \\\approx 0.92965~\text{days}
$$

(Where the extra half-day comes from the `pm`.)

The subdivisions of the day would be:

$$
\begin{align}
1~\text{day (d)} &= 1~\text{day} \\
1~\text{deciday (dd)} &= \frac{1}{10}~\text{day} = 2~\text{hours}~24~\text{minutes} \\
1~\text{centiday (cd)} &= \frac{1}{100}~\text{day} = 14~\text{minutes}~24~\text{seconds} \\
1~\text{milliday (md)} &= \frac{1}{1000}~\text{day} = 1~\text{minutes}~26.4~\text{seconds} \\
1~\text{microday ($\mu$d)} &= \frac{1}{10^6}~\text{day} = 86.4~\text{milliseconds}
\end{align}
$$

For fun you can come up with nicknames for the different units.  E.g. deciday could be "metric hour," "deci," or (based on the abbreviation `dd`) a "dud."  Milliday could be "metric minute" or "mid."

We could add an additional "convenience unit" also based on the powers of ten:

$$
1~\text{metric second (s$_\text{m}$)} = \frac{1}{10^5}~\text{day} = 0.864~\text{seconds}
$$

So we might write our time from before (`10:18:42 pm`) in metric time as:

$$
9~\text{dd}~29~\text{md}~65.3~\text{s}_\text{m}
$$

Or simply as `9:29:65` or even `0.92965`.

This makes the representation of dates easy too, since we can just put a whole number of days in front of the decimal point.  In fact, we could throw away months altogether and just use day numbers.  For example, today is `2016-02-11` (eleventh of February, 2016).  January has 31 days, so February 1 is day 32, and February 11 is day 42.  Thus, in the metric calendar today is "day 42 of 2016."

Putting it altogether, `10:18:42 pm, Feb 11, 2016` is `42.9:29:65, 2016`.

---

All joking aside, this is close to a real time system: the [Julian Date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day).  There are a lot of variants, but they all count decimal days from some starting point.

Let's use the same date from before as an example.  In the "traditional" Julian date, `2016-02-11T22:18:42` is equal to `JD 2457430.429653`.  Note that the decimal part is almost the same, but there is a difference of `0.5`.  The Julian date starts at noon, not midnight—it was invented by astronomers, and this way it doesn't roll over in the middle of the night when they are doing their observations.  Note also that I assumed our time was in GMT: there is no concept of time zones for the Julian date, so we need to convert the time to GMT before converting to JD.

There is also the "modified" Julian date, defined as `MJD = JD − 2400000.5`.  Our example time is `MJD 57429.929653`.  The modified Julian date is used frequently in the space industry because it it shorter than the full Julian date (and easier to represent in computers with limited precision) and it starts at midnight like most other time systems (where the factor of `0.5` comes from).

Fun fact: the ["stardates" of Star Trek](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Stardate) were based on the concept of the Julian Date.

---

One final point: I mentioned time zones in the previous section, and for a large country like Canada time zones are pretty much a necessity (although China seems to be OK without them).  There are two options:

- Base the metric time on the real local time.  So if you're in Ottowa (EST/UTC-5), and the local clocks say `10:18 pm`, then your metric clock would say `9:29`.  At the same time in Vancouver (PST/UTC-8), the local clocks say `7:18 pm` and your metric clock would say `8:04`.  This is the easiest to implement, since you can just do the calculation based on the phone's local time, which is usually what you get from the builtin date functions by default.  The differences between the time zones are not a whole number of duds or mids, but that's just the kind of wierd, stupid stuff that happens in real life.
- Make up your own time zones!  This makes the app logic nontrivial and is probably too far for a joke app; but I like to think about this sort of stuff, so here goes.

  If we restrict ourselves to time zone offsets of whole duds, then there are only ten timezones in the world, each about 36 degrees wide.  Canada is wide enough to have three of them (so there is a two-dud difference between the eastern and western time zones).  In order to make things plausible, I'll make the metric time zones by merging the real time zones to make our lives a little easier.

  The `+0` timezone is centered on 0 degrees longitude.  The "ideal" dividing lines would be 18 degrees to either side, so the western edge (dividing the `+0` and `-1` time zones) passes right through Iceland.  The `-1` timezone is 36 degrees wide and includes most of Greenland, just cutting through the easternmost tip of Canada.  The `-2` timezone includes most of the Great Lakes, stopping just before the west tip of Lake Superior.  The `-3` timezone contains Alberta, Saskatchewan, and Manitoba.  It ends just after the west coast of the United States.  The `-4` time zone includes the west half of British Columbia and the Yukon.

  These ideal divisions actually line up fairly well with existing time zones. The new `-2` time zone lines up with `UTC-4` (Atlantic time) and `UTC-5` (Eastern time).  The new `-3` includes `UTC-6` (Central time) and `UTC-7` (Mountain time).  Finally, the new `-4` time zone includes `UTC-8` (Pacific time), as well as `UTC-9` (Alaska time).  You might call the new time zones "Eastern Metric Time," "Central Metric Time," and "Pacific Metric Time" (with abbreviations EMT, CMT, and PMT).

  For the actual implementation, I would get the current UTC time from the date libraries and convert it to metric time.  Then find the user's current UTC offset, and map it to one of the new time zones (all the cases above are just `newTZ = floor(oldTZ / 2)`), then add or subtract that many duds from the metric time.  The borders would shift during DST (e.g. locations using PDT move to the `-3` time zone, and locations on CDT move to the `-2` time zone), but we can live with that.  The `floor(TZ / 2)` trick seems to work reasonably well across the rest of the world too.

Comment: Woah, this was *way* more detail than I was expecting, thank you so much for your answer! If there is any interest, I might be able to publish the final metric time app to the App Store for others to enjoy (at their friends expense lol).

Comment: @ACE I happen to have thought about this before, so the answer was kind of "ready-to-go" in my head.  As for the app, I forgot to mention that you probably will have to implement time zones since Canada has a difference of 4 hours (sorry, 0.16 decis) between its coasts.  I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: The app is only meant to sell a prank, but if there is actually a market for something like this, I could add time zones and post it to the store...

Comment: @ACE Even if you don't actually implement timezones, I feel having a fake timezone option would really sell it (as well as add to your victim's confusion!)

Comment: And I thought just going to POSIX time would be strange enough.

Comment: "You need make sure you set your clock to EMT."  "Eastern time?"  "No, Eastern *Metric* Time... what, you don't have that option?  I can show you can app that does..."

Comment: Hmm, for the prank time zones works well. If we're properly going to metric time I'd advocate for ditchnig both timezones and daylight saving time though. Does it really matter if you wake up at 8am or at 13 duds? It's just a number to represent a time. Eastern canada might start school at 11:00 duds and western at 13 duds but that's not a problem.

Comment: @TimB Personally I'm against converting to one "universal" time zone but I'm all for elimination of daylight savings.  But, I think that's a discussion for another question.

Comment: @2012rcampion someone needs to make a timezone map based on your idea of timezones. If i include that in the app, the believability factory will go up by 100.

Comment: "metric second", your so evil

Comment: @PyRulez Well, it *is* a prank >:)

Comment: @2012rcampion okay, hitting some snags while implementing this... how would I convert the decimal date (`.92965` in your example) to the `9 dd 29 md 65.3 sm` ?

Comment: @ACE It works the same way that you convert (say) a number of seconds into a list of hours, minutes, seconds.  Something like `deciday = (int)(day * 10); milliday = (int)(day * 1000) % 100; msec = (int)(day * 100000) % 100;`

Comment: If conversion to integer type rounds instead of truncates (or like Javascript you don't have an integer type) then use a `floor` function instead.

Comment: @ACE Sorry, Windows + Android user; it looks like we must part ways here.  I wish you luck!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I couldn't have gotten this far without it.

Comment: @2012rcampion quick follow-up, the friends I'm recruiting to help execute this prank were wondering if it is possible to create a metric time system that is easy to explain (100 seconds in a minute, 100 minutes in an hour.etc) but without having to implement a large time-jump at midnight...

Comment: @ACE Well, the the length of the day is not a rational number of SI seconds.  So you have to give up one of: 1) the day having a power-of-ten division into its subunits, 2) the smallest subunit being a rational number of SI seconds, or 3) the time system staying in sync with the astronomical day-night cycle.  You can't have all three, you *have* to pick one to discard.

Comment: @ACE So the answer to your question is *yes, but...*  For example, if you used "100 seconds in a minute, 100 minutes in an hour," then the day is 8.64 hours long.  You can either give up (1) and have a "time jump at midnight," or give up (3) and have the day be 10 hours long, with solar noon coming 1 hour, 36 minutes earlier every day.  You'd get two solar noons in one "metric day" roughly once a week.  I gave up (2) in my system, since (3) is highly desirable and (1) seems necessary for the concept to work cleanly.

Comment: @ACE Note however that you don't have to think of (1) as requiring a "time jump."  After all, we don't think "there's a date jump of 70 days at the end of the month," we just know that the month is 30 days long (or 31, or 28, or 29).  Similarly, you don't have to say "the time jumps forward 1.36 hours at midnight," you just say "the day is 8.64 hours long" so 8:63:99 rolls over to 0:00:00, just as March 31 rolls over to April 1.

Comment: fun little extra bonus thing that i found. apparrently base-10 time was actually created: https://youtu.be/N0U-XEmKPKg?t=1077

Answer (score 7):

The method I've always used is 10 hours per day, 100 minutes per hour, 100 seconds per minute, like 2012rcampion suggests.

Then there are ${24\over 10}=2.4$ normal hours per metric hour, ${24\cdot 60\over 10\cdot 100}={1440\over 1000}=1.44$ normal minutes per metric minute, and ${24\cdot 60\cdot 60\over 10\cdot 100\cdot 100}={86400\over 100000}=0.864$ seconds per metric second.

If you're building your own clock on a microcontroller or using small electronics, you'd want to update the metric second every 864 normal milliseconds.

If you're just writing software on a laptop or mobile device that has simple access to normal time functions, then you can just get the current time of day in seconds.

I used Visual Basic.Net, made a couple labels, two textboxes, and a timer set to update every 50 milliseconds (though you could do it less often, especially if you're not showing both times back-to-back).

Here's the VB.Net code using VS 2013. Create a new forms project, create a textbox named `txtNormal`, another named `txtMetric`, a timer named `timClock` then paste the code into the class file and it should work.

`Private Sub timClock_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles timClock.Tick
  Dim Now As Date = DateTime.Now
  Dim normalSeconds As Integer = Now.Second
  Dim normalMinutes As Integer = Now.Minute
  Dim normalHours As Integer = Now.Hour
  Dim totalSeconds As Double
  Dim metricSeconds As Double
  Dim metricMinutes As Integer
  Dim metricHours As Integer
  totalSeconds = Now.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds
  metricSeconds = 100000 * totalSeconds / 86400
  metricHours = Math.Floor(metricSeconds / 10000)
  metricSeconds -= metricHours * 10000
  metricMinutes = Math.Floor(metricSeconds / 100)
  metricSeconds -= metricMinutes * 100
  metricSeconds = Math.Floor(metricSeconds)
  txtNormal.Text = normalHours.ToString("00") + ":" + normalMinutes.ToString("00") + ":" + normalSeconds.ToString("00")
  txtMetric.Text = metricHours.ToString("00") + ":" + metricMinutes.ToString("00") + ":" + metricSeconds.ToString("00")
End Sub`

Here are several screen grabs of a simple program running with different time zones:
[image: Imperial: 00:25:23, Metric: 00:17:63]
[image: Imperial: 05:26:30, Metric: 02:26:74]
[image: Imperial: 10:27:00, Metric: 04:35:42]
[image: Imperial: 11:58:15, Metric: 04:98:78]
[image: Imperial: 16:58:43, Metric: 07:07:44]
[image: Imperial: 21:29:19, Metric: 08:95:36]
[image: Imperial: 23:30:00, Metric: 09:79:17]

If you want to go further, you can turn weeks into 10-day periods, with 36.5 weeks per year, though obviously there's no way fully convert to a base-10 metric calendar without adjusting the Earth's rotation.

Of note, [France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_time#France) actually used this exact time system from 1794 to at least 1801, although it was mandatory only until 1795, and they used a 10-day week from 1800ish to 1805. In their system, the clock and units were called "decimal" instead of "metric", even though they introduced the metric system at the same time, and they sometimes used the unit "décime", one-tenth of a decimal hour, or ten decimal minutes. During this era, astronomer [Pierre-Simon Laplace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre-Simon_Laplace) used a decimal watch that ended up being the basis for astronomers using the decimal time 2012rcampion mentions in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

I am going to point you to an existing solution, which is somewhat similar to what you are suggesting, but not sure whether this is what you want. [Hackworth](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11290/hackworth) has also mentioned it in a comment.

There's a time system named [Swatch Internet Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swatch_Internet_Time). This was invented by Swatch (hence the name).

The day is divided into 1000 beats. That makes one beat around 1 min 26 seconds long. So 500 beats would be noon, 250 beats 6 am etc. (The clock doesn't have time zones, so those times would be UTC+1, but of course you could ignore that for your purpose. There's a [converter](http://www.swatch.com/en/internet-time) on the Swatch website)

What makes this neat in my opinion is that 1 second, corresponds to 0.011574 .beats, which is almost 0.01. So if you make a clock or an app, the change in this decimal will be virtually indistinguishable from seconds. So you could have an indicator for this second decimal and it will 'tick' just as fast as a second indicator on a normal clock.

Comment: Note that 1:1.15740740740740... is the same as the 0.864:1 we've already suggested. It's actually fairly easy to note the difference when they're back to back, though it might be harder if you're just looking at the metric clock. A standard minute has 60 standard seconds or 69.4 metric seconds, which is a pretty large discrepancy.